# Dictionary based string matching algorithm - Java

Tags: java, algorithm, similarity

Is there any dictionary based string matching algorithm in Java?

Something that will give the percentage of similarity between two strings based on the dictionary ?

Like

```
 public double getSimilarity(String str1, String str2);
```

for which an implementation like :

```
 getSimilarity("Professor", "Teacher")
```

will give a very high percentage ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Relating a "Professor" to a "Teacher" is something that us Humans can do quite easily. To a computer these are just two different sequences of characters. You are going to have to do all the heavy lifting for the computer for a problem like this.

Comment: Just run it through a thesaurus ;)

Comment: You may need a ontology for your topic which can be analysed to get a measure for 'similarity'.

Comment: @Sanchit Thanks god for Artificial Intelligene, Natural Languages Processing and Statistical approaches. This problem is actually addressed in many researches, so don't give up too early, though they are only "a sequence of characters", given the correct context - you can learn  a LOT on what is the meaning of each, and how they are related one to the other.

Comment: Downvoters: Please elaborate why the downvote. I find it very helpful and very clear what the OP is asking.

Comment: It looks like the OP wants an easy solution, I'm trying to make him realize how little the computer knows. Of course you can attach your brainless computer to another computer that knows the answer already but I doubt the OP has one of those lying around. He's going to have to hook his computer up to a giant Thesaurus and then when his program figures out that flammable and inflammable mean the same thing, its brain might explode. I just want him to know that this isn't exactly an easy problem to solve. It IS solvable though given that you have a good criteria for what is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great work done by Shaul Markovitch and Evgeniy Gabrilovich, described in their article: [Wikipedia-based Semantic Interpretation for Natural Language Processing](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~shaulm/papers/abstracts/Gabrilovich-2009-WBS.html).

The idea is as follows: Index wikipedia (or other context source).

Creating a mapping for each term (word): `term -> articles in which the term appears in`.

Each term is basically represented by a *vector* - for simplicity, let's say it is a binary vector - so for the term `t` the entry `d` will be '1' if and only if the term `t` appears in the document `d`.

Now, given these vectors - to find if two terms `t1`, `t2` are similar - all you have to do it take the *vector similarity* of the two vectors that represent `t1` and `t2`.

---

Note: The binary vector is a simplification, in fact the article uses the [tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) score, that the term `t` has in a document `d`.